# Color fraction bar

Tags: math-mode, color, amsmath, fractions

What would be the easiest way to create a fraction whose bar can be coloured as desired? I know one can use the `\genfrac{left-delim}{right-delim}{thickness}{mathstyle}{numerator}{denominator}` command but I can't seem to get. The following is a MWE (not so much if you can see):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
$\genfrac{}{}{0.4pt}{}{a}{b}$
\end{document}
```

### UPDATE

Applying Herbert's solution below yields something weird. See below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\Frac#1#2{ #1 \color{red}\above 0.4pt \normalcolor #2}

\begin{document}

$ \Frac{n+1}{n-1} $$\displaystyle \Frac{n+1}{n-1} $

\end{document}
```

Note the denominator of the second is of the same size as the first fraction.

Comment: `{\color{red}\genfrac{}{}{0.4pt}{}{\color{black}a}{\color{black}b}}` works, but may be there are better approaches.

Comment: @Manuel That would be the obvious, brute force, way but thanks for the input.

Comment: Brute force, but I think it's quite similar to the other possible solutions.

Comment: @Manuel Sure I know and thanks again for the input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Herbert, I was able to tap into the `amsmath` package documentation and come up with a modified version of the `\frac` command definition. The documentation has the following:

> Bury the generalized fraction primitives `\over`, `\atop`, etc.,
>   because of their bizarre syntax, which is decidedly out of place in a
>   LaTeX document.
>
> ```
> \@saveprimitive\over\@@over
> ```
>
> If someone insists on using `\over`, give a warning the first time and
>   then resurrect the old definition. Laissez-faire policy.
>
> ```
> \DeclareRobustCommand{\primfrac}[1]{% \PackageWarning{amsmath}{%
> Foreign command \@backslashchar#1;\MessageBreak \protect\frac\space or
> \protect\genfrac\space should be used instead% \MessageBreak }
> \global\@xp\let\csname#1\@xp\endcsname\csname @@#1\endcsname
> \csname#1\endcsname }
> ```

Hence the warning that LaTeX shouts out in @Herberts answer. The documentation continues by saying that

> `\frac` calls `\@@over` directly instead of via `\genfrac`

and defines `\frac` as

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\frac}[2]{{\begingroup#1\endgroup\@@over#2}}
```

This where I modified the definition of `\frac` slightly to come up with the command `\cbfrac` which stands for `colored bar fraction` just for my own reference. See the definition below:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cbfrac}[3][OrangeRed]{{\begingroup#2\endgroup\color{#1}\@@over\normalcolor#3}}
```

Here is MWE illustrating how it works:

[image]

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\Frac#1#2{ #1 \color{red}\above 0.4pt \normalcolor #2}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cbfrac}[3][OrangeRed]{{\begingroup#2\endgroup\color{#1}\@@over\normalcolor #3}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\noindent
$ \Frac{n+1}{n-1} $
$\displaystyle \Frac{n+1}{n-1} $\\[1ex]
$ \cbfrac{n+1}{n-1} $
$\displaystyle \cbfrac{n+1}{n-1} $
\end{document}
```

Commenting the command `\Frac` removes the warning.

Answer (score 3):

`\genfrac` refers to `\over` or `\above` which are primitives. But you can define an own `\frac` which uses `\above`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\Frac[3][]{ #1 #2\color{red}\above 0.4pt \normalcolor #1#3}

\begin{document}

$ \Frac{n+1}{n-1} $$\Frac[\displaystyle]{n+1}{n-1} $

\end{document}
```

Comment: This issues a warning: `Package amsmath Warning: Foreign command \above;(amsmath) \frac or \genfrac should be used instead
(amsmath)`

Comment: By analyzing your solution, are the following also valid: `\def\Frac#1#2{ #1 \color{red}\above 0.4pt  \normalcolor #2}
\def\Frac#1#2{ #1 \begingroup\color{red}\above 0.4pt\endgroup   #2}`

Comment: You may want to play it doubly save and encase `#1` in a `\begingroup`/`\endgroup` pair. (That's the LaTeX and amsmath way at least.)

Comment: @azetina you're right. see texdoc `technote` page 2

Comment: @azetina:  the amsmath warning is no problem. And yes, using `\normalcolor` is the better way.

Comment: Did you see the update to my question?

Comment: @azetina: see my edited answer

Comment: Smart, really smart idea. It is a shortcut to obtaining the desired effect.