# How to color a fraction bar in mathematical mode?

Tags: fractions

when I use the [solution given here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149963/138900), this is what I get:

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110979/138900
\usepackage{amstext} % for \text
\DeclareRobustCommand{\officialeuro}{%
  \ifmmode\expandafter\text\fi
  {\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{eurosym}\selectfont e}}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149731/138900
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\Frac#1#2{ #1 \color{blue}\above 0.4pt \normalcolor #2}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cbfrac}[3][OrangeRed]{{\begingroup#2\endgroup\color{#1}\@@over\normalcolor #3}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\SI{18}{\euro\highlight{blue}\per\kilo\gram}=\frac{\EUR{18}}{\SI{1}{kg}}$
\bigskip

The same with color and Frac
\bigskip

$\SI{18}{\euro\highlight{blue}\per\kilo\gram}=\Frac{\EUR{18}}{\SI{1}{kg}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149963/197451

Comment: What's the purpose in using the wrongly defined `\Frac` command?

Comment: @egreg What are you talking about?

Comment: @AndréC Well, `\cbfrac` works *a lot* better.

Comment: @egreg I'll take your word for it. It emulates `\frac` who writes the text in small and I would like to be able to emulate `\dfrac` to write the text in larger. How do you do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd prefer the `\cbfrac` version. Here I present a slight modification based on `\genfrac`.

Note that the color in the denominator is the same as the current color, which would not be true with `\normalcolor`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}

% text doesn't mind if it's called in text mode
\DeclareRobustCommand{\officialeuro}{%
  \text{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{eurosym}\selectfont e}%
}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149731/138900
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cgenfrac}[5]{%
  \def\@tempa{#2#3}%
  \edef\@tempb{%
    \@nx\@cgenfrac{#1}%
    \@mathstyle{#5}%
    \csname
      @@%
      \ifx @#4@over\else above\fi
      \ifx\@tempa\@empty\else withdelims\fi
    \endcsname
  }%
  \@tempb{#2#3#4}%
}
\newcommand\@cgenfrac[6]{%
  {#2{\colorlet{current}{.}\begingroup #5\endgroup\color{#1}#3#4\relax\color{current}#6}}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\cbfrac}[3][blue]{\cgenfrac{#1}{}{}{}{}{#2}{#3}}
\newcommand{\cbdfrac}[3][blue]{\cgenfrac{#1}{}{}{}0{#2}{#3}}

\begin{document}
$\SI{18}{\euro\highlight{blue}\per\kilo\gram}=\frac{\EUR{18}}{\SI{1}{kg}}$
\bigskip

The same with color and cbfrac
\bigskip

$\SI{18}{\euro\highlight{blue}\per\kilo\gram}=\cbfrac{\EUR{18}}{\SI{1}{kg}}=
\cbdfrac{\EUR{18}}{\SI{1}{kg}}=
\dfrac{\EUR{18}}{\SI{1}{kg}}$

\bigskip

\textcolor{red}{$\cbfrac[green]{1}{2}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need another pair of braces in the definition of `\Frac` to delimit the scope of `\above`. If you don't want to shrink the denominator and the numerator, you have to add `\displaystyle` to both (implemented here as `\FRAC`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\officialeuro}{%
  \ifmmode\expandafter\text\fi
  {\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{eurosym}\selectfont e}}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\Frac#1#2{{#1\color{blue}\above0.4pt\normalcolor#2}} % <<< Note the double braces
\def\FRAC#1#2{{\displaystyle#1\color{blue}\above0.4pt\normalcolor\displaystyle#2}}
\begin{document}
$\SI{18}{\euro\highlight{blue}\per\kilo\gram}=\Frac{\EUR{18}}{\SI{1}{kg}}$

$\SI{18}{\euro\highlight{blue}\per\kilo\gram}=\FRAC{\EUR{18}}{\SI{1}{kg}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the difference:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
With \verb"\def\Frac#1#2{#1\above1pt #2}",\\
\verb"$A\Frac{B}{C}D$" typesets as
\def\Frac#1#2{#1\above1pt #2}$A\Frac{B}{C}D$.
\bigskip

With\verb"\def\Frac#1#2{{#1\above1pt #2}}",\\
\verb"$A\Frac{B}{C}D$" typesets as
\def\Frac#1#2{{#1\above1pt #2}}$A\Frac{B}{C}D$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in this issue. This macro now actually changes the color of the bar correctly, but the characters are written as with the macro `\frac` whereas I would like them to remain written in bulk as with the macro `\dfrac`.  Is that possible?

Comment: @AndréC I have updated the answer. Just add twice `\displaystyle` in the definition of `\Frac`.

Comment: Thank you can you give the code for both versions in your answer, the one emulating `\frac` and the one emulating `\dfrac` so that it is exhaustive?